# UITextField placeholder text is truncating with "..."

Tags: swift, placeholder, truncation

My placeholder text (i have a IB `UITextfield`) is not resizing even though i have done this:

```
textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
textField.minimumFontSize = 1
```

I tried using this:

```
 let attributedplaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholderText, 
                         attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: 
                         UIFont(name: "fontName", size: 10)!])
 textField.attributedPlaceholder = attributedplaceholder
```

But this gives Exception:

```
exception Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7fd04359b200>) doesn't 
                   contain a view controller with identifier 'xxx'
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Also i do not know how to use `adjustFontSize` to fit width when using `attributedplaceholder` ?

Can somebody help here ?

Thanks.

Comment: As it is formatted, your question is not readable. Can you please use the formatting options available here and make your question more appealing to the community? Welcome to SO.

Comment: Note that the convention is not to use CamelCase (like `TextField`) in Swift for variable and property names. Use names like `textField` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think **"Regular 18.0"** is not a valid font name. You can lookup what fonts you have by the following:

```
    for familyNames in UIFont.familyNames() {
        for fontNames in UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyNames) {
            print(fontNames)
        }
    }
```